# How to select MAX in a sub query in Linq to Sql

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Given the following data, how does one select only the latest version for each item using LINQ?

```
ItemId, Version
===================
A, 1
A, 2
A, 3
B, 8
B, 9,
C, 10
C, 11
```

The desired results are:

```
A, 3
B, 9
C, 11
```

In TSQL, I would do something like so:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable AS Tbl1

WHERE Tbl1.Version = 

(SELECT MAX(Version) 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE MyTable.ItemId = Tbl1.ItemId)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with something like:

```
MyTable
.GroupBy(row => row.ItemId)
.Select(grouping => 
    new
    {   
        ItemId = grouping.Key, 
        Version = grouping.Max(row => row.Version),
    });
```

EDIT: Fixed bad SQL output.

Comment: But, he was asking how to return all columns on "MyTable", not just Id and Version

Comment: @drogon His table only has `ItemId` and `Version` though. You can only get the Max for the columns you choose to aggregate by, otherwise it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

```
        var data = new[] {
            new { item1 = "A", item2 = 1},
            new { item1 = "A", item2 = 2},
            new { item1 = "A", item2 = 3},
            new { item1 = "B", item2 = 8},
            new { item1 = "B", item2 = 9},
            new { item1 = "C", item2 = 10},
            new { item1 = "C", item2 = 11}
        };

        var res = data.GroupBy(el => el.item1).Select(gr => new { item1 = gr.Key, item2 = gr.Max(el => el.item2) });

        foreach (var el in res)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(el.item1 + ": " + el.item2);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select itemid, max(version)
from table
group by itemid
```

Comment: He wanted the answer in Linq-2-Sql

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer query syntax:

```
from item in MyDBContext.MyTable
group item by item.ItemId into g
select new { ItemId = g.Key, Version = g.Max(x => x.Version) };
```